# Imported function name clash with current module function name in JS

Tags: javascript

The odds are that this question has been asked many times, but still can't find the answer.

Imagine I have two modules A and B, and function `foo` defined in module A. In module B, I have a function foo which needs `foo` from A:

module B:

```
import { foo } from './A'


export const foo = (payload) => {
    foo() // meaning module A function  
}
```

I get error

> Identifier 'foo' has already been declared

Any way to solve this leaving the function names the same ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot leave the identifiers the same, you need to alias either the imported one

```
import { foo as aFoo } from './A'

export const foo = (payload) => {
    aFoo()
};
```

```
import * as A from './A'

export const foo = (payload) => {
    A.foo()
};
```

or change the local function name:

```
import { foo } from './A'

const bBoo = (payload) => {
    foo()
};
export { bFoo as foo }
```